# PHP input/file not picking up file to upload

Tags: php, elgg

I am pretty new to [Elgg](http://elgg.org/) and I am trying to allow users to upload a video. My problem could also just be php related, however.

So I have set up my form with the following code:

```
echo elgg_view("input/file", array('name' => 'video', 'accept' => 'video/*'));
```

which sets up a control to allow users to upload files. My action file is filled with  a lot of defensive programming to ensure that the file is there. When I try to upload a video, I get the following error which points me to this snippet of code:

```
// must not be empty if a file is present in the upload
    if( empty($_FILES['video']['name']) ) {
        $error = elgg_echo('No file to upload!');
        register_error( $error );
        forward( REFERER );
    }
```

I am completely lost at where the problem may lie, I have been trying to achieve this for about 2 days now. I have been referring to a bunch of other plugins which make use of file uploads in Elgg, such as the file plugin and the TidyPics plugin.

All help and tips are appreciated in advance. Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that your video file size is less than [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/post_max_size) and/or [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/memory-limit)?

Comment: I have not, would that make a difference? The video I am trying to upload is only 2MB large. I also tested other files and they return the same error. I also tried appending $_FILES['video']['error'] to the error but it just returns blank?...

Comment: Default value for `post_max_size` in `php.in` is 2MB, so if your file + any other data is 2.01MB or larger, it will cause the upload to fail and `$_FILES[]` will be an empty array.

Comment: Ahh, I did not know that. I am going to try and increase the post_max_size in the php.ini file and see if that works.

Comment: The php.ini file has post_max_size = 128M in it, the maximum size cannot be the problem?

Comment: Is your form enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: The form enctype is something I was looking for earlier, the problem is I am using the Elgg social network framework, which handles all of that automatically. I will look into that and maybe I can change it or something. But if I look at other plugins that upload pictures it is exactly the same set up as how I have set it up. Unless videos and pictures are different?

Comment: @Sean that was the problem! Argh, stressing over this for so long! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! The file now uploads and saves! Thanks to everybody who replied/commented, your help is much appreciated! Sean, if you want to post that as an answer so I can add a correct answer to this question.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, including a link to the elgg wiki docs that show that `enctype` defaults to blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Forms

> Enctype form attribute (defaults to blank). You will need to pass a
>   value of 'multipart/form-data' if you want your form to do a file
>   upload.

try-

```
echo elgg_view('input/form', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', ...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a print_r($_FILES) right before your if statement followed by an exit() to see if that will give you some clues. I would have posted this as a commented, but I don't have enough rep points yet cuz I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: No problem. I will try that quickly.

Comment: I get a blank screen with "Array ( )" printed. I am assuming this means that there is nothing there? No file selected?

Comment: If I try to print_r( $_FILES['video']['name'] ) or just $_FILES['video'] then a blank white screen is returned.

Comment: the browser isn't sending the file to the server, or the server is rejecting it b/c of size limitations. can you copy/paste the html markup of the opening form tag? What is your form enctype attribute? It should be multipart/form-data (don't quote me exactly).....oh wwait NVM someone else already said the same thing

Comment: @mimber thanks :), the answer has been solved. It was the enctype attribute that was not set.